# Ubuntu 20.04 Could NOT find MPIR during gr-iio cmake

Tags: git, ubuntu, cmake, gnuradio-companion

For the third time I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 on a Windows 10 machine running VMWare whilst attempting to install GNU Radio Companion 3.8 with the PlutoSDR gr_iio blocks. Each time failed with a different error.

I am charting my most recent attempt below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

1. Installed Ubuntu 20.04 on VMWare
2. Updated Ubuntu
3. `cp ./53-adi-plutosdr-usb.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/`
4. `sudo service udev restart`
5. checked the output of `dmesg`
6. Since I had no `~/.ssh/config` file I ran `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/analogdevicesinc/plutosdr_scripts/master/ssh_config -O ~/.ssh/config`
7. `ssh plutosdr` to add to list of known hosts. I verified the IP and firmware version.
8. `sudo apt-get install libiio-utils` and verified I can talk to the device via `iio_info -n 192.168.2.1 | grep device` The following output was produced:

```
IIO context has 5 devices:
    iio:device0: adm1177
    iio:device1: ad9361-phy
        18 device-specific attributes found:
                attr  2: dcxo_tune_coarse ERROR: No such device (-19)
                attr  4: dcxo_tune_fine ERROR: No such device (-19)
    iio:device2: xadc
        1 device-specific attributes found:
    iio:device3: cf-ad9361-dds-core-lpc (buffer capable)
    iio:device4: cf-ad9361-lpc (buffer capable)
                attr  3: samples_pps ERROR: No such device (-19)
                attr  3: samples_pps ERROR: No such device (-19)
```

I checked the errors shown above on the ADIEngineerZone and a top 1%er said "You can ignore these errors."
[https://ez.analog.com/adieducation/university-program/f/q-a/111133/missing-device-attributes-after-update-of-pluto/331921#331921](http://You%20can%20ignore%20these%20errors.)

So I did just that (since I couldn't find a solution to resolve it) and moved on to the final check for lined items three through eight.

9. `iio_readdev -n 192.168.2.1 -s 64 cf-ad9361-lpc | hexdump -x` returned values just fine

Now that the Linux drivers are installed I proceeded to check the output of `iio_info -s` and `iio_info -u ip:192.168.2.1`. The first returned expected results. The second output was terribly long but notable errors showed after the /gaintable tag

```
                .
                .
                .
                attr 10: multichip_sync ERROR: Permission denied (-13)
                attr 11: rssi_gain_step_error value: lna_error: 0 0 0 0
mixer_error: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
gain_step_calib_reg_val: 0 0 0 0 0
                .
                .
                .
```

I am not sure if this is an issue, but considering the prior excusable error, I moved forward with the installation as outlined below.

I begin by installing dependencies for GNU Radio.

```
cd
sudo apt-get -y install libxml2 libxml2-dev bison flex cmake git libaio-dev libboost-all-dev swig libgmp-dev liborc-0.4-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libserialport-dev graphviz doxygen
```

No errors were seen.

Next, for `git clone` I installed using the following prefix `/usr/local`, which I'll take note when setting and checking the PATH.

```
git clone https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio.git
cd ~/libiio
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ../
make
sudo make install
cd

git clone https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libad9361-iio.git
cd ~/libad9361-iio
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ../
make
sudo make install
cd

git clone https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/gr-iio.git
cd ~/gr-iio
git checkout upgrade-3.8
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ../
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Because I ran into a problem with the gr-iio `cmake` stating:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

I read online I should update `apt-get`, soemthing I should of done from the beginning but never stated in any walk-through.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential`

I deleted the build folder after the above update and reran the gr-iio portion.

After the update, the CXX compiler was found. However, I did get an error not finding a package configuration file:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:90 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindGnuradio.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Gnuradio",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Gnuradio"
  (requested version 3.9) with any of the following names:

    GnuradioConfig.cmake
    gnuradio-config.cmake
```

So I looked for the two stated files so I can add to the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH but using:
`find /usr/ -iname GnuradioConfig.cmake` or
`find /usr/ -iname gnuradio-config.cmake`

returned nothing... Online searching showed me I would need to `sudo apt install gnuradio-dev` so I did that and reran `cmake`

This time it resulted in an error stating:

```
--   No package 'mpir' found
-- Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

On to installing mpir:

`sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev` and back to another go at removing the build directory and rerunning cmake. But, still same issue:

`-- Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR)`

All online documentation points to installing `libgmp3-dev` or `libgmp-dev` but neither resolve this issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The project named "GNU Radio and IIO Devices" which you have cloned from https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/gr-iio.git is NOT a GNU Radio project and this project by itself depends from GNU Radio (this is clearly written in the [project's documentation](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/gnuradio). If you want to build GNU Radio project, then see there:https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR#From_Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to the [documentation](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/gnuradio), the `gr-iio` project doesn't include the `GNU Radio` project but expects you to build it in advance.

However, you only built `libiio` and `libad9361`, but not the `GNU Radio` library from https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio. The config file `gr-iio` is complaining about should be installed when installing `GNU Radio`.

Regarding MPIR: While MPIR started as a fork of gmp you can't install gmp as a replacement for MPIR, as they use different names for their headers and libraries. Which is why MPIR is still not being found after you've installed the development packages for gmp. If ubuntu doesn't provide packages for MPIR you'll have to compile it from source.

Comment: Thank you. The documentation shows things out of order then. I will install GNU Radio from build and if it works, rewrite this as a guide to help others. 

I'm sure I'll re-post/modify if I have issues.

Comment: @JamesHayek I've extended the answer to include a section to explain why installing `libgmp-dev` doesn't work.

Comment: So far I was able to build everything. I will set my PATHs tonight test GRC. Pain in the butt to build MPIR. If all is well, (since I lost my process doing much back and forth) I will attempt on a new Virtual machine and document my steps this week.

Comment: Well, after all that... I run a file in GRC and it spews out no iio module.
I go back and set my PYTHONPATH (again) but this time include a path to iio.py and now all my QTGUI blocks are missing. I'm at my wits end, I was so close.