# GNU Radio Companion: No Module Named iio; import iio shows fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, iio

I have been working to install GRC on my Windows 10 hosted, VMWare Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I have tracked my efforts here:
[Ubuntu 20.04 Could NOT find MPIR during gr-iio cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66402771/ubuntu-20-04-could-not-find-mpir-during-gr-iio-cmake/). After much trouble, I was able to install GRC 3.8 with dependencies and `cmake` files built with no errors.

In my `.bashrc` file, I set my paths to the following:

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio:/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio:/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/iio:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After refreshing using: `. ~/.bashrc`
I launch GRC from the terminal and I am showing missing blocks for QT. I notice my block paths are:

```
Block paths:
    /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
```

BUT, when I launch GRC from the application launcher I am able to see my QT Blocks. The block paths now show:

```
Block paths:
    /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
    /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
```

But, that's just one mystery. Another is the failure to `import iio` for ether method of launching. In GRC, I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iio'`

However, when I take to terminal and type `python3` and then `import iio` I get a return character.

What's going on here?

Comment: It's likely you have multiple Pythons on your system.  If you type `which -a python3`, do you see buth /usr/bin/python3 and /usr/local/bin/python3?

Comment: I do see two directories in the output, I see `/usr/bin/python3` and `/bin/python3`
How is this caused and how can I correct it?

Comment: One of them has your modules, one doesn't.  You just need to make sure the right one gets picked.  You can create a symbolic link to the right one in ~/bin, and make sure ~/bin comes first on your path.

Comment: Interesting. I noticing both directories have the same files. When I check the total count I see they are the same 

`jameshayek@ubuntu:~$  ls /usr/bin/ | wc -l
1738`
and `jameshayek@ubuntu:~$ ls /bin/ | wc -l
1738`

Comment: Do you have /usr/local/bin/python3 or /usr/local/bin/python?

Comment: I have neither... only `/usr/bin/` and `/bin/` show when typing `which -a python3`

The folder you mentioned `usr/local/bin` has files:

`f2py  grcc   gr_plot  gr_plot_qt     iio_info  list_cpu_features
f2py3 gr-ctrlport-monitor gr_plot_const  gr_read_file_metadata iio_readdev     polar_channel_construction  f2py3.8 gr_filter_design gr_plot_fft    iio_adi_xflow_check iio_reg volk-config-info
gnuradio-companion gr_modtool  gr_plot_iq iio_attr iio_stresstest  volk_modtool gnuradio-config-info  gr-perf-monitorx  gr_plot_psd iio_genxml             iio_writedev  volk_profile`

Comment: i.e., `jameshayek@ubuntu:~$ ls /usr/local/bin/python*` returns:
`ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/python*': No such file or directory` Should it be there in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: `jameshayek@ubuntu:~$ ls /usr/bin | grep python` shows the same as `ls /bin | grep python` Which would be:
`dh_python2
python2
python2.7
python3
python3.8
python3.8-config
python3-config
python3-futurize
python3-pasteurize
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config
`